# Testing webapp2: Login required not recognized

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have the following in app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: app.application
  secure: always
  login: required
```

When running tests I'm using this [testrunner](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting?hl=en#Python_Setting_up_a_testing_framework) as suggested by google.

```
class SearchTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        # Set up app simulator
        app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/search', search.Search)], debug=True)
        self.testapp = webtest.TestApp(app)

        # Google testbed
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()

        self.testbed.init_user_stub()
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
        self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()

        # Disable caching to prevent data from leaking between tests
        ndb.get_context().set_cache_policy(False)


    def testNotLoggedin(self):
        # Test user is redirected to login when not logged in

        assert not users.get_current_user()

        response = self.testapp.get('/search')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_int, 302)
        assert response.headers['Location']
```

The testNotLoggedIn fails with 200 != 302. So it seems like the user is still allowed access even though login is required. Which makes me think that app.yaml isn't recognized in the test?

How can I make sure that app.yaml is recognized and that the user needs to be logged in?

Comment: I believe those rules are handled by the dispatcher before it gets to your application. There isn't a good way to test that without starting an instance of dev_appserver and testing via HTTP to that server.

Comment: Though in the testrunner I linked to it looks like you import dev_appserver...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test code bypasses the `app.yaml` dispatch. On App Engine (and in a dev server), the HTTP request is routed to the WSGI application instance via `app.yaml`, and the frontend logic that handles `login: required` happens before the request handler is invoked. In this test code, you're going directly to the WSGI application: `self.testapp.get('/search')` is simply calling the WSGI app's own internal URL mapping to get to the `search.Search` request handler.

The condition you want to test is more like an integration test, and requires either a running dev server or a deployed App Engine test version. It's a fine idea, it's just larger than what `testbed` et al can do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). I ended up adding login_required to each of the handlers in the meantime. That way I can still test it without going to through too much effort with creating a larger integration test thingie.